# Getting unexpected result from NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I have the following code:

```
var num = 0.03829585
let amountNumber = NSNumber(double: num)
let nFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
nFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
nFormatter.roundingMode = .RoundHalfUp
nFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
var numStr = nFormatter.stringFromNumber(amountNumber)!
```

The expected result of `numStr` is "0.03829585". That is what I get with my test devices, but on a small number of my TestFlight users' devices I get "0,03829585". Why is that? How can this be fixed so that I always get the right string representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSNumberFormatter takes the locale in the consideration. The devices can have set their locale to a country where the people use a comma in the place of the point. This is a feature, not a bug. People use NSNumberFormatter specialy for the localisation feature. If you want the point to be everywhere you can simply transform that double into a string (don't do it). That doesn't only take care of the point/comma problem, it takes care for the digits, for example persian digits are different then the digit we know

Comment: What if I start with a NSNumber instead of a double, how would I always get the string with the decimal point?

Comment: Why do you want a "." for users who use and expect "," as the decimal point? Would you be happy if a European developer forced a "," on you as the decimal point?

Comment: @user69450 let double = nsNumber.doubleValue

Comment: @user69450 In your code I don't understand why you make an NSNumber, when Int,Double,Float are bridged to NSNumber (not backwards)